# Got "Ambiguous handler methods mapped for '/v3/api-docs'" after migrating from SpringFox to SpringDoc

Tags: spring-boot, springfox, springdoc

Using Spring Boot 2.4.5 and IntelliJ 2021.2. After migrated

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Everytime I access `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html`. The page says:

> Fetch errorundefined /v3/api-docs

and when I check the logs:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for '/v3/api-docs': {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity springfox.documentation.oas.web.OpenApiControllerWebMvc.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest), public java.lang.String org.springdoc.webmvc.api.OpenApiWebMvcResource.openapiJson(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.String) throws com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException}
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:426)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:377)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:125)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:67)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:498)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1257)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)

There is seemingly a duplicated handler method with the same path from SpringFox and how would I remove the one from SpringFox (It no longer exist in my pom file)?

Comment: Look around for Springfox dependencies by performing a dependency analysis and get rid of them. You seem to have removed `springfox-boot-starter` but from what I recall, there should be another Springfox dependency for the Swagger-UI

Answer (score 10):

Remove the swagger dependencies, springfox dependencies. Only adding  openapi dependencies are enough.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. I had the dependency `springfox-boot-starter` in my project and removing that worked.

Answer (score 4):

Do you still have both dependencies? I had the same problem, except with webflux. After some digging I discovered the following:

- springdoc-openapi-webflux-core-1.5.10: OpenAPIWebfluxResource.class
- springfox-oas-3.0.0: OpenAPIControllerWebFlux.class

Both these classes create handlers for the "/v3/api-docs" mapping. They are incompatible as is warned by the springdoc documentation:

https://springdoc.org/#differentiation-to-springfox-project

> 11.35. Differentiation to Springfox project
>
> - OAS 3 was released in July 2017, and there was no release of springfox to support OAS 3. springfox covers for the moment only swagger 2 integration with Spring Boot. The latest release date is June 2018. **So, in terms of maintenance there is a big lack of support lately.**
> - ...
> - We rely on on swagger-annotations and swagger-ui only official libraries.
> - ...

> 11.36. How do I migrate to OpenAPI 3 with springdoc-openapi
>
> - There is no relation between springdoc-openapi and springfox.If you want to migrate to OpenAPI 3:
> - Remove all the dependencies and the related code to springfox
> - Add springdoc-openapi-ui dependency
> - If you don’t want to serve the UI from your root path or there is a conflict with an existing configuration, you can just change the following property:
>
> > springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/you-path/swagger-ui.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this: `springdoc-openapi-ui` + `springfox-swagger2`, instead of `springfox-boot-starter`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by adding a new controller (I named it

```
HomeController) with this mapping.
@GetMapping(value = {"/", "/swagger-ui", "/swagger-ui+html"})
public String index() {
    return "redirect:/swagger-ui/index.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i just change /v3/api-docs to /v2/api-docs and it work

Comment: Please update with your spring boot or/and springdoc version

Answer (score 0):

I wrote SwaggerFilter

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class SwaggerFilter implements Filter {
   @Override
   public void doFilter(
           ServletRequest request,
           ServletResponse response,
           FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

       HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

       if (req.getRequestURI().equals("/v3/api-docs")) {
           RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher("/v2/api-docs");
           dispatcher.forward(req, response);
       } else {
           chain.doFilter(request, response);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. Could you please explain a bit in your words what the code is doing?

Comment: Its java filter which forward to /v2/api-docs if condition true. Its java basic